# Inventory with both a hostname and IP address pattern

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using the `vmware_guest` module to create a bunch of vms.

**Is there anyway to use a pattern for both the hostname and IP address?**

For example I want to create 5 master vms with hostname/IP like:

- `master1` `10.123.0.1`
- `master2` `10.123.0.2`
- `master3` `10.123.0.3`
- etc.

So an inventory yaml with something like the following:

`all:
  children:
    Elvis:
      children:
        masterNodes:
          hosts:
            master[1-5]:
              ansible_host: 10.123.0.[1-5]
        slaveNodes:
          hosts:
            slave[1-10]:
              ansible_host: 10.124.0.[1-10]`

---

**Also, is there a way to run a playbook for a specific `parent:child` group?**
How can I run a play for `Elvis:masterNodes` only? If for instance, the same inventory yaml has another parent child group `Bono:masterNodes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use a pattern for both the hostname and IP address?

No. Instead, Ansible allows running a script to generate an inventory - it is trivial to implement a loop populating inventory-hostname along with IP address in Python (apparently it was made clear as early as in [July 2013](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3614#issuecomment-21338632), although in the same thread someone suggested [a workaround](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3614#issuecomment-21324712)).

> Also, is there a way to run a playbook for a specific parent:child group?

No. There is no hierarchy in Ansible inventory; the namespace is flat; there are no child groups; Ansible operates on host/group sets.

In effect, you can't have distinct (sub)groups bearing the same name. The contents of those (sub)groups will be merged. So if `Elvis` contains a group `masterNodes` and you execute a play with `hosts:Elvis` declaration, it will run on all hosts defined for `masterNodes` anywhere (including in `Bono:masterNodes`).